# Java SQL Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to insert the data below into a table that has the columns ID[autoNumber], type[text], to[text], from[text], message[text] and attachmentLoc[text]

So the autonumber is generated I insert them supplying the column names. When it runs the console prints out:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3149)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:216)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:138)
at MultiEchoServer.saveMessage(MultiEchoServer.java:147)
at ClientHandler.run(MultiEchoServer.java:409)
```

The code that is bringing the error is :

```
try
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Messages (type, to, from, message, attachmentLoc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";     
        PreparedStatement stmt = database.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, message.getType());
        stmt.setString(2, message.getTo());
        stmt.setString(3, message.getFrom());
        stmt.setString(4, message.getMessage());
        stmt.setString(5, attachmentLoc);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not perform statement");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could it be because I am using the word from in my database?

Comment: Yes it was because it was a reserved word :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From is a reserved word, after this was changed to messageFrom it allowed the insertion  to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what database engine you're using, but a number of the column names (as well as the table name) are likely candidates for reserved words.  The very most obvious is `from`.

You will need to write those identifiers in *identifier quotes* which are generally either the backtick character (`) or the characters [ and ] (depending on engine):

```
INSERT INTO `Messages` (`type`, `to`, `from`, `message`, `attachmentLoc`)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO [Messages] ([type], [to], [from], [message], [attachmentLoc]) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);
```

The quoting is only required around the identifiers that are reserved words but using it around all identifiers will not hurt.  Also, no reason not to include the space after VALUES and the semi-colon at the end of the statement (although most engines don't need either).

Comment: I answered my own question, thanks anyway. It was because from was a reserved word. I change the column name to messageFrom

Comment: Different engines establish different lists of reserved words.  I'd watch out for `type`, `to`, and `message` as well.  Obviously they're not reserved in whichever SQL product you're using now but if you switch out the engine later it's something to be aware of.

Comment: PS: When you answer your own question, you should post it as an answer, not a comment, then (after a brief delay) you can mark your own answer correct.  You don't score points for accepting your own answer, but it removes the question from the "still open" list and helps people who come along in the future find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need valid syntax for the INSERT statement.  SQL does not understand the question mark.

Perhaps, you want one of the following:

- '?'
- NULL
- ''

Or some other value.

So, assuming the columns accept NULL values, you could use:
     VALUES(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Comment: Those are parameters placeholders.