# Syntax error in query mdb java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I have created a application using Java which connect to the MDB file, it writes read and modify data success fully.
I have tested it on WIndows 7 32 bit. 
Now I have shipped every thing on the other machine and created system DNS and all as it was on the earlier machine but the application started to give error for the following query

```
insert into tblCredentials(NameCode,Password) values(72,'reset123')
```

Along with that it also started to give error to many INSERT INTO statement which are working on the other machine.

The error I get is

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in
 INSERT INTO statement.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at timesheetserver.MDBHandler.executeUpdateQuery(MDBHandler.java:99)
```

I cant find anything wrong in it and moreover it is working on one of my WIndows & machine.

What can be the problem 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @TheNewIdiot As I have mentioned in the post Error is :Syntax Error in the INSERT INTO statement

Comment: Paste the full sql error please .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Added complete stack trace

Comment: Do you have the table script for tblCredentials? What if your NameCode is alphanumeric? In that case you would need the '' in the query. Maybe you have a datatype mismatch on both machines.

Comment: @Martin No data base file same copied along with the application so thats not possible. I do not have script for tblCredentials i have created it using MS Access on the my dev machine (XP) NameCode is Number of field size Long Int.

Comment: @Martin And not only this INSERT INTO started to give error there are few others which are working perfectly fine on the other machine

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214664/java-sql-syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement I have never used Access from Java, but might it be that Password is a reserved word?

Comment: @Martin No that is not the case I have checked that also

Comment: According to this page, it is: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx Have you tried using identifier quotes with your NameCode and Password fields? Maybe you have different Access or ODBC Driver versions which react differently with such an issue...

Comment: @Martin thanks The list which I saw is not having that word. Ok let me modify  and check it Will let you know the result

Comment: @ Yipee!!! SOlved at least this one. I will also check the other INSERT statement and see which are the reserved words in it . Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page, PASSWORD is a reserved word for Access: office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/…

Have you tried using identifier quotes with your NameCode and Password fields?

Maybe you have different Access or ODBC Driver versions which react differently with such an issue...

Comment: I would like to add a point here. This is a case only when you are using the ExtendedAnsiSQL support . If you dont require this support then simply set ExtendedAnsiSQL to 0 while creating the System DNS